# Need to search Partial text in list within list

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, search

I have lists within list and need to return index of list based on matching partial text.

```
stock1 = [['fiscal year from Jan', 2013,2014,2015],['Net Income in billions, '2.4B','3.5B','4.1B'],['Net Expense in billions', '1.6B','2.4B','3.5B']]

stock2 = [['fiscal year from June', 2013,2014,2015],['Net Income in billions, '1.5B','2.1B','2.8B'],['Net Expense in billions', '0.7B','1.4B','2.1B']]
search = 'fiscal'
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(stock1) if search in s]
print(indices)
```

It prints [] instead of [0].

It's possible that beginning of Fiscal is different. Sometimes it is Jan and sometimes it is June. So I need to search only using word 'fiscal'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look inside the first variable of each list (which is the description) instead of generally in the list:

`indices = [i for i, l in enumerate(stock1) if search in l[0]]`

I've annotated it with `l` which stands for list, instead of `s` as enumerating over a list of lists result in lists being extract.